# How do I delete all the emails from one sender to my Gmail

Tags: gmail

I wish to continue receiving from this sender but I wish to delete all past received emails from him.

Comment: Search for them and then delete in bulk?

Answer (score 4):

Use a search string "From:email@address", select all emails (if you have more than fits on the same page, also click "Select all conversations that match this search"), and delete.